# Akka + Camel: Wildcard match of Jetty endpoint

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I wanted to try to match an akka actor that is being used as a akka-camel consumer with jetty to a wildcard. For instance, I want everyone of the following to go to the same akka-camel consumer:

```
http://<ipaddr>:8080/
http://<ipaddr>:8080/path1
http://<ipaddr>:8080/path1/subpath1
http://<ipaddr>:8080/path2
```

With the following as a simple akka-camel consumer:

```
class CamelActorConsumer extends Consumer {
  def endpointUri = ""jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/"
  def receive = {
      case x: CamelMessage =>
         println("Got: " + x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer I could find was to provide akka-camel with a wildcard matcher in the `endpointUri` as follows:

`def endpointUri = ""jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8877/?matchOnUriPrefix=true"`

This will match all of the above paths. We can change it to be just sub-directories under a particular path by adding to the path before the `?matchOnUriPrefix=true`